# Angularjs - Sweet alert on popup(dialogbox) window

Tags: angularjs, sweetalert

I am trying to do something, that I'm guessing should be fairly easy, but I can't figure it out I googled a lot noting helped.
scenario is like when I click on a button I will get one popup window through angularjs popup directive in that popup I will multiple iframe with cancel button when I click on cancel button it delete that iframe but before deleting the frame it will confirm through sweet alert but, sweet alert popup is displaying behind the frames popup which is not visible until I close the frames popup...

Below is the code

this button help me to open the popup which contain multiple iframes.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mar-5" ng-click="openPopup('displaywidgets')" style="width:20%">WIDGETS</button>
```

This is the code which will display all the iframes in popup window

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="displaywidgets" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="z-index:10000 ">
```

This code display the cancel icon to delete

`<i class="fa fa-remove" ng-click="deleteWidget(widget)"></i>`

This is the controller method which display the sweet alert

```
    $scope.deleteWidget = function(widget) {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this widget!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!"
    }, function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
         alert("deletewidget");
            widgetFactory.deleteWidget($scope.oemToken, widget.id)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.init();
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    swal({
                        title: "Error!",
                        text: "Error in deleting Widget",
                        type: "error"
                    });
                });
        }
    });
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked about z-index?

Comment: Yes Z-index worked for me. but, background is not getting blur, I mean background options should not perform until I do some performance on sweet alert

Comment: You need to do some stuff at there as you haven't provided working code snippet here, i guess something workaround can take place at some place.